# Is it common to use the word "commute" instead of "go" in conversation?

Tags: word-usage

I talked to a Canadian person yesterday. She used the word "commute" instead of "go" or "get." For example, she said "I commute to work by car." and asked me "How do you commute to work?"

It was a bit odd to me to see a person use "commute" instead of "go" or "get." So, I want to know whether is it common to use "commute" instead of "go" or "get"?

Comment: Yes, it's common in American English as well. "3
: [to travel back and forth regularly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commute) (as between a suburb and a city)....He commutes to work every day by train. She commutes 400 miles a week."

Comment: @BillFranke Do you mean that saying "I commute to work by train" or "I go to work by train" are both common?

Comment: Yes, they're both common. Generally, I'd say that using _commute_ is more common when the distance traveled is long and the time required is more than, say, 30 minutes. I used to _commute_ to work here in Taiwan because I had to ride my motorcycle for more than 30 minutes every day, but when I moved into the city, I merely _drove_ or _went_ to work because it took me just 10 minutes.

Comment: No, *commute* does not mean *go*.

Comment: [commute  verb = travel to work: drive, go back and forth, take the bus/subway/train](http://thesaurus.com/browse/commute?page=1&o=100074&qsrc=121). You can also commute to a hospital or doctor's office for medical treatment. IOW, even though _commute_ is not a synonym for _to go_ when _to go_ means _to go to the store_, for example, it means _to go by vehicle_ to work or some other usually regular activity. If _commuting to work_ (_traveling by vehicle to work_) is not _going to work_, then it must mean something rather arcane, like _not going to work_ or _staying home from work_, mustn't it?

Comment: [Cognitive dissonance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance) {CD} is alive & well on EL&U. Another way of looking at this theory is by reading Aesop's fable _The Fox & the Grapes_. The fox suffers from CD when he can't get the grapes. He lies & says that they were probably sour anyway. The OP's Q asked about "going to work" and "getting to work". Most people _commute to work_. Some of us work at home or close to home & don't have to _commute_. One's lexical religion is irrelevant to whether _I **commute** to work by car_ means _I {**go/get**} to work by car_. It obviously does.

Answer (score 3):

It's common to use the word "commute" in the specific context of going to and from one's workplace.  However, it's not a general replacement for "go"; for instance, I wouldn't say "I'm commuting to the store" instead of "I'm going to the store".